# Problem with getting UserName using webservices in InfoPath

Tags: 2010, infopath

I have SharePoint 2010 and InfoPath 2007. I am using the webservices to get the user name into the forms text box. I have followed this post and its works fine:

[InfoPath - Get the current user without writing code](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/itaysk/archive/2007/04/05/InfoPath-_2D00_-Get-the-current-user-without-writing-code.aspx)

I followed the post to the letter and it works. I logged in as Admin and deployed the form and I get the Admin as the user name. But now when I log in using different user credentials the username doesn't update and I still get the same Admin user name

Do I need to do some additional things other than the blog post? Please suggest

Comment: Check step '7. Click next and make sure Automatically retrieve data when form is opened is checked.'

Comment: Yeah I already did that and I as I mentioned I followed the steps exactly. Please suggest.

Comment: Just to check: Are you using browser-enabled forms or are you opening forms in InfoPath?

Comment: Forms opening in Infopath

Comment: And this is issue then! Look at end of my answer. I didn't see your last comment before posting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed post step by step and it works fine. When I log with different user I receive different data. So there are two options how to solve your problem this:

Start from scratch

or just to verify everithing is ok insert a button and add two rules to it:

1. Set field value of GetUserProfileByName > QueryFields >
   tns:GetUserProfileByName > AccountName to function userName()
2. Query For Data > GetUserProfileByName

Try to click button and see if your data is still same. If answer is yes - problem is outside of your Infopath form.

This was all tested on InfoPath 2010 with browser enabled forms deployed on SP Form library.

Addition:
It is obvious that if you open form in InfoPath client application (and not in browser enabled form) current InfoPath user will be current Windows user not user logged in SharePoint.

Comment: Hello, I used the browser enabled forms and installed the State Service Application. Then I published the form and it works fine. Thank you for your suggestion